# How can I insert a Bootstrap modal, containing AngularJS, using .innerHTML then manually open it?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When my page loads this is what I am trying to get it to do:

```
$(function () {
    urlExtract = location.hash
    foundExtract = urlExtract.split("#/")[1];
    if(foundExtract == "zsexdr"){
        var createModal = "";

        basicRep = document.getElementById('basicReports');

        createModal+='<div class="modal fade" id="#waiverModal" role="dialog">';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-content">';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-header">';
        createModal+='<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
        createModal+='<h4 class="modal-title">{{z.name}} - Downloads</h4>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-body">';
        createModal+='<span ng-repeat="z in waiverModalLinks" class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}{{z.title}}">{{z.title}}</a></span>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-footer">';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='</div>';

        basicRep.innerHTML+=createModal;

        $('#waiverModal').modal('show');
    }
})
```

The modal gets created and inserted into the HTML just fine, except that the AngularJS isn't registering, where it does register for other angular within the same `div id="basicReports">` I am using `ui.bootstrap` and I have gotten AngularJS to be inserted into a modal on a different page, but this is the first time I am attempting to insert the modal dynamically and have it opened programmatically. So I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

My main problem is, along with the Angular not registering, the modal is not opening. I know the modal is there because if I inspect element I can see it in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for angular to parse the html.

The modal is not opening because in the html you have specified the modal id as `#waiverModal` instead of just `waiverModal`. Also since you already have `jQuery` on the page you can use jQuery methods for DOM manipulation.

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('AVS', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('BasicInformation', function($scope, $compile){

   $scope.basicreports = [
   {name: 'Online Edit', link: 'url', status:''},
   {name: 'Project Log', link: 'url', status:''}

   ];

   $scope.waiverModalLinks =[{
      title:"Title",
      link:"Links",
      color:"color?"
   }];


    var urlExtract = location.hash,
    foundExtract = urlExtract.split("#/")[1];
    if(foundExtract == "zsexdr"){
        var createModal = "", 
        basicRep = $('#basicReports');

        createModal+='<div class="modal fade" id="waiverModal" role="dialog">';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-content">';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-header">';
        createModal+='<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';
        createModal+='<h4 class="modal-title">{{z.name}} - Downloads</h4>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-body">';
        createModal+='<span ng-repeat="z in waiverModalLinks" class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}{{z.title}}">{{z.title}}</a></span>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='<div class="modal-footer">';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='</div>';
        createModal+='</div>';


        createModal = $compile(createModal)($scope);


        basicRep.append(createModal);

        $('#waiverModal').modal('show');
    }

 });

})();
```

Comment: Derp on the # mistake with the id name, my bad. Fixing that makes the modal open indeed. However, applying the rest of your changes the code breaks entirely. Doesn't even do an alert after the `if` statement. I tried adding just the compile portion; breaks. I tried changing the code over to JQuery methods, rather than using `document.getElementById` and `.innerHTML`; breaks.

Comment: You have to make sure angular js in loaded on the page and you are runing this peice of code in a directive or controller.

Comment: OHH this code needs to be in the controller as well?? Alrighty.

Comment: In or out of controller? Originally I was putting this code in a separate js file than my Angular controllers.

Comment: You can try without having controller.

Comment: When I added old version of answer to controller, it completely broke the Angular on the page. JSHINT gave me like 5 warnings for this line:`createModal = $compile(createModal){scope);` And I tried your new version of answer out of controller: same thing, breaks code. Tried it in controller: same thing, breaks Angular on entire page.

Comment: Can you setup a plunkr?

Comment: Any time I attempt to set one up that involves using angular I always fail to get it working, but I can take a crack at it, just might take me some time: either to be successful or to realize it's not happening lol.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/c9LK7quqhDb93JRZI2Zr?p=preview That's my best attempt to get it working the way my code works. I don't *ever* have success with replicating angularjs results.

Comment: I have fixed the plunkr and other code. Take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/c9LK7quqhDb93JRZI2Zr?p=preview

Comment: Did you save it? It looks just like mine did when I left it. And I know I've accidentally forgotten to save before posting.

Comment: I did save it but looks like it gave an error which I ignored. I changed it again here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/BEgicBh3napMSjiekqT8?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! That is awesome. Now I know how to implement AngularJS interpolations in HTML placed by JQuery using $compile. That is awesome. Thank you so much for working with me on getting this working! You should edit your answer to have the final solution and plunkr in there.

Comment: Hey, you wouldn't happen to know why if I wrap the this code in `$(function(){$('#htmlelement').click(function(){ //JQuery code });});` that the modal still opens..but is completely empty? (removed the `location.hash` portion, turns out I need this modal to be placed and opened when I click a link rather than when the page loads). Would like to avoid having to ask another question! Would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: You can add the condition. I had commented it out to test in the plnkr.

Comment: That condition is for finding the # in the URL, which yes, needed to be commented out in order to work in Plunker, and works superbly in my code. Thing is, now I don't want to look for the # but instead have the code run when an HTML element is clicked using the JQuery `.click` function. So I have removed the following lines `var urlExtract = location.hash,` | `foundExtract = urlExtract.split("#/")[1]; | `if(foundExtract == "zsexdr"){` | And instead have the click function. The modal pops up but it is empty. I will see if I can work in the plunker.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/MTVU8kvtjUIQvytX59Jw?p=preview Like that. When you click on one of the buttons. Completely empty where the Angular interpolations are. Except for `{{z.name}}` but that one doesn't even belong, it's outside of the `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in going a bit more full-bore into the "AngularJS Way" of doing things, you should check out Bootstrap UI, which is Twitter Bootstrap written in pure angular, without any dependency on jQuery.

I think this would provide you with a much cleaner, simpler, and more maintainable way to create this modal because of the tight integration between your Angular controller, directive, and modal template.

Here's the link directly to the Bootstrap UI Modal demo and sample code:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

If you're interested in going down this path, I'll add and edit to this answer to take a shot at doing the same thing you're doing above as a Bootstrap UI modal. It'll get rid of all of those HTML strings and replace them with nice clean data binding.

**EDIT**
Here's a more "Angular Way" of dynamically building the modal:

JS:

```
angular.module('dynamicModalExample', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])

 .controller('MainController', function($scope, $location, $modal) {

     $scope.data = {
         name: 'sampleName',
         waivers: {
             id: 'sampleId',
             link: 'sampleLink',
             title: 'sampletitle'
         }
     }

     $scope.urlExtract = $location.path()
     $scope.foundExtract = $scope.urlExtract.split("#/")[1];

     if(foundExtract == "zsexdr"){
        $scope.showModalBtn = true;
     }else{
        $scope.showModalBtn = false;
     }

     // Might want to use a ternary operator instead of if/else like this:
     // $scope.showModalBtn = foundExtract == "zsexdr" ? true : false;

     $scope.open = function () {
          $modal.open({
          animation: true,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          resolve: {
              items: function () {
              return $scope.data;
              }
          }
        }
     });
 })

 .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {

     $scope.waiverModalLinks = data.waivers;
     $scope.name = data.name;

     $scope.ok = function () {
       $modalInstance.close();
     };
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <button ng-if="showModalBtn" ng-click="open()">
        Show Downloads Modal
    </button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{name}} - Downloads</h4>'
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span ng-repeat="z in waivers" class="{{z.id}}">
                <a href="{{z.link}}{{z.title}}">{{z.title}}</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing a more "Angular way" method. I guess I didn't think to use the modal on that site, even though I use the Accordion elsewhere in my site, using the `ui.bootstrap` dependency. So, that wouldn't be hard, but the main reason I am bringing in JQuery into the mix is to dynamically put the modal on the page, and when a certain string is detected in the URL when the page loads. I'm still fairly new to the Angular world and have a heck of a time with data-binding.

Comment: I would love to find out how I can accomplish this same task doing it the pure "Angular way" but I did have to mark ShankarSangoli's answer as the correct answer on account of it did answer the question at hand. You would be providing probably a more favorable method though that I am sure will receive upvotes. And I will probably convert my code anyway because I am always changing my code as I learn a more "Angular way" of doing it.

Comment: Ok cool - and no worries - @shankarsangoli did answer the question.

Comment: And yes, angular is a major mind-shift when you come from a jQuery background, so I understand why your initial instinct was to do it this way.

But, yes, there is a much more "Angular way" to dynamically build this modal...

So, to do stuff based on the URL, I'd recommend using ngRoute for simple routing (is sounds like this may work for you) or UIRouter for more complex routing
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute and 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Not sure how to do that in a plunker though...

I'll edit my answer when I have a chance.

Comment: I have read into routing stuff and that is personally when my brain shuts off. It is too complex for me, but that could be because I have never seen a working example on something I could understand. When it comes to coding, I can't read documentation and know exactly how I can implement it into my code or what use it could be in code in general. I have to actually need it, seek it, and use it to really understand it! So to see a working example on code I understand would be super beneficial!

Comment: Okay - I edited my answer with a code sample - does that help?

Comment: Ok, this does look easy enough to implement. Here is issue though...so what is happening here is that the modal is already on the page, but the specifications of the modal is defined depending on if `#/zsexdr` is found in the URL, making it so the modal is set differently depending on what is in the URL? I guess the diff is we are dynamically *building* vs dynamically *placing*. I'm trying to do this without editing the HTML because it would be like 10 diff files I would need to edit, not hard, but then makes them diff than our other ones for diff clients. Which I guess is being avoided. :)

Comment: This could still be very useful for me in the future however, so I am definitely starring this to find it easily later. I will have to play with it to fully understand what the different aspects of the code are achieving!